# update <ONE> from <MANY> in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

i have a query

```
UPDATE
    users u
SET
    amount = u.amount + b.sumwin
FROM
    bonus b
WHERE
    b.user_id = u.id AND
    b.pay = 0 AND
    b.autopay = 1 AND
    b.sumwin > 0;
```

One user record relate with many bonus records. How i can add sumwin from bonus to user account? Queries above don't do anything o.O

Comment: some test data would be nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with cte as (
    select b.user_id, sum(b.sumwin) as sumwin
    from bonus as b
    where
        b.pay = 0 and
        b.autopay = 1 and
        b.sumwin > 0
    group by b.user_id
)
update users as u set
    amount = u.amount + b.sumwin
from cte as b
where b.user_id = u.id;
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/49861/7)</kbd>**

Your query should work partially, i.e. add sumwin from one arbitrary row. From [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html):

> When using FROM you should ensure that the join produces at most one
>   output row for each row to be modified. In other words, a target row
>   shouldn't join to more than one row from the other table(s). If it
>   does, then only one of the join rows will be used to update the target
>   row, but which one will be used is not readily predictable.

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/49861/9)</kbd>**

Comment: yea, thank. i know, it work. i want think why query above do not work?